# Obtain different answers if we change the order of integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

In Wolfram alpha, it gives us

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} dydx=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} dxdy=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Why do we have two different answers if we perform the order of integration differently?

I tried to look up the Fubini's theorem condition, but to no avail. Because the integral above satisfies Fubini's theorem.

Did I miss up something?

Answer (score 2):

The integral does not satisfy [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem). In particular see [this part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Failure_of_Fubini.27s_theorem_for_non-integrable_functions) (similar to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)#Basic_theorems)).

The article states:

> One may switch the order of integration if the double integral yields a finite answer when the integrand is replaced by its absolute value.

However,

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left|\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\right|\,dx\,dy$$

is not finite, so the theorem does not apply.

---

To see the above integral is not finite,

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left|\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}\right|\,dx\,dy
&=& \int_0^1 \left(\int_0^y \frac{y-x}{(x+y)^3}dx+\int_y^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dx\right)dy\\
&\ge& \int_0^1 \int_0^y \frac{y-x}{(x+y)^3}dx\,dy = \int_0^1 \int_y^{2y} \frac{2y-u}{u^3}du\,dy\\
&=& \int_0^1 \left[\frac{u-y}{u^2}\right]_{u=y}^{2y}\,dy = \int_0^1 \left[\frac{x}{(x+y)^2}\right]_{x=0}^y\,dy\\
&=& \int_0^1 \frac{1}{4y}\,dy = \frac14 \bigl[\ln(y)\bigr]_{y=0}^1\\
&=& \frac14 \left(\ln(1) - \lim_{t\to 0} \ln(t)\right) = \frac14 \bigl(0 - (-\infty)\bigr)\\
&=& \infty
\end{eqnarray}

where $u = x+y$ was the substitution used in the middle.

Comment: How to tell the double integral with absolute value is not finite?

Comment: @Idonknow See my edit.